# Little compactness exercise

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I'm don't know ho to solve this exercise, especially (ii)

> $I=[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$. Let's consider the topology $\tau$ over $\mathbb{R}$ generated by the sets $[a,b): a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> (i)Show that $I$ is a closed set
>
> (ii)Show that $I$ is not compact.
>
> ---

(i)
First of all I see that also the sets $(a,b): a < b$ are open sets, because $(a,b)=\cup_n [a-\frac{1}{n},b)$.

The complementar set of $I$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is $(-\infty,0) \cup (1,+\infty)$, and this sets are open, in fact $(-\infty,0)=\cup_{x<0}(x,0)$. Conversely for $(1,+\infty)$. So $I$ is closed.

(ii)I start taking an open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $I$. But for every open cover I take, I always find a finite subcover... which open cover should I take?

Thanks :)

Comment: Hint that might help: an open cover can cover *more* than the set you're covering. In particular, you can take $[1,2)$ as one of the sets in your open cover.

Comment: yes I know, but I don't know how to find the special cover which has no finite sub-cover...

Comment: Note that the rest that you have to cover is $[0,1)$, which is not even compact in the coarser Euclidean topology, so certainly not in this one.

Comment: You can also prove that $(-\infty,0$) is open  by saying  it equals $ \cup_{x<0}[x,0).$ This topology is called the Sorgenfrey line, or the lower-limit topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is OK. The topology is finer than the usual topology , so at least has the same closed sets.

For the second, consider $U_1 = [0,\frac{1}{2}) , U_n = [1-\frac{1}{n} ,1-\frac{1}{n+1})$ for $n \ge 2$ and $U_0 = [1,2)$ to cover $1$.

Then $[0,1] \subset \cup_n U_n$ but it has no finite subcover, as we have a disjoint cover of non-empty sets.

Comment: Or the open cover $\{[0,x): 0<x<1\}\cup \{[1,2)\}$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I wanted to refute countable compactness too...

Comment: OK . I hadn't noticed that.